# Facebook Graph API - Get Likes count by Facebook Page ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Graph API and is it possible to get the like account for a Facebook Page by ID?

I have tried the following URL:

[https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}?fields=name&access_token={my_api_access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bpage_id%7D?fields=name&access_token=%7Bmy_api_access_token%7D)

And I get this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Page Public Metadata Access requires either app secret proof or an app token",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "Ac1RaXdc4MG24eJ3UnYkIz7"
   }
}
```

My Facebook account is not associated with this Facebook Page. Is not possible to get the likes for a certain Facebook Page or do I have to be an admin to that Facebook Page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to submit your app for review of the mentioned feature first.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference#page-public-metadata-access

Comment: Okay done. Hopefully it does not take long. Side question: Would Instagram Public Content Access allow me to get  instagram  followers count for another account?

Comment: Would you happen to know how long an app review takes?

Comment: No, I don’t know what the current turnaround times are for that.